# Cloudformation creating a Lamba with it's associated Role

Tags: aws-cloudformation

Cloudformation is bringing me mad... I've the following cloudformation script

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "Lambda Function + IAM role Resources",
    "Resources": {
        "NFTCalculateCIDLambdaRole": {
            "Type" : "AWS::IAM::Role",
            "DeletionPolicy": "Retain",
            "Properties" : {
                "AssumeRolePolicyDocument" :{

                    "Version": "2012-10-17",
                    "Statement": [
                        {
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Principal": {
                                "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
                            },
                            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "Description" : "Role for execute CalculateCID lambda function",
                "ManagedPolicyArns" : [ "arn:aws:iam::670818552530:policy/PutLogsEventPolicy", "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess" ],
                "RoleName" : "NFT-CalculateCIDLambdaRoleTEST"
            }
        },
        "InterpolazioneRole": {
            "Fn::Join": [
              "", [
                "arn:aws:iam::",
                {
                  "Ref": "AWS::Account"
                },
                ":role/",
                {
                  "Fn::GetAtt": ["CalculateCIDLambdaRole", "RoleName"]
                }
              ]
            ]
        },
        "CalculateCID":{

            "Type" : "AWS::Lambda::Function",
            "DeletionPolicy": "Retain",
            "Properties" : {
                "Code": {
                    "S3Bucket": "deploy-stack",
                    "S3Key": "CalculateCID-3496f166-0f1d-40b4-8766-c5d29e4950ff.zip"
                },
                "Description" : "Calculates the CID for a given filename",
                "Environment" : {
                    "Variables": {
                        "DELETE_S3_FILE_AFTER_PROCESSING": "true",
                        "TMP_DOWNLOAD_BUCKET": "content-temporary-files"
                    }
                },
                "FunctionName" : "CalculateCID",
                "PackageType" : "Zip",
                "Role" : "Fn::Join",
                "Runtime" : "Node.js 12.x"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but when I execute it I got

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStackSet operation: Invalid template resource property 'Fn::Join' (Service: AmazonCloudFormation; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID: 106e6351-a4b9-41a4-9d8d-fe2ff6902e87; Proxy: null)
```

The problem is I don't know how to pass the arn geneated at previous step.. anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Lambda Functions, Role has to be mentioned with its Arn. You can use return values from [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html#aws-resource-iam-role-return-values) document for the IAM Resource. You are trying to create a resource using Join Function which you cannot. Refer the arn of the IAM Role directly from the Lambda.

Update your Cloudformation Role property with `Fn::GetAtt` and remove the unused resource.

```
"Role" : {"Fn::GetAtt" : ["NFTCalculateCIDLambdaRole", "Arn"] }
```

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "Lambda Function + IAM role Resources",
    "Resources": {
        "NFTCalculateCIDLambdaRole": {
            "Type" : "AWS::IAM::Role",
            "DeletionPolicy": "Retain",
            "Properties" : {
                "AssumeRolePolicyDocument" :{

                    "Version": "2012-10-17",
                    "Statement": [
                        {
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Principal": {
                                "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
                            },
                            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "Description" : "Role for execute CalculateCID lambda function",
                "ManagedPolicyArns" : [ "arn:aws:iam::670818552530:policy/PutLogsEventPolicy", "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess" ],
                "RoleName" : "NFT-CalculateCIDLambdaRoleTEST"
            }
        },
        "CalculateCID":{

            "Type" : "AWS::Lambda::Function",
            "DeletionPolicy": "Retain",
            "Properties" : {
                "Code": {
                    "S3Bucket": "deploy-stack",
                    "S3Key": "CalculateCID-3496f166-0f1d-40b4-8766-c5d29e4950ff.zip"
                },
                "Description" : "Calculates the CID for a given filename",
                "Environment" : {
                    "Variables": {
                        "DELETE_S3_FILE_AFTER_PROCESSING": "true",
                        "TMP_DOWNLOAD_BUCKET": "content-temporary-files"
                    }
                },
                "FunctionName" : "CalculateCID",
                "PackageType" : "Zip",
                "Role" : {"Fn::GetAtt" : ["NFTCalculateCIDLambdaRole", "Arn"] },
                "Runtime" : "Node.js 12.x"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are getting error because you are trying to create InterpolazioneRole as join resource rather than a role resource.  Join is function not a resource object .

So create  InterpolazioneRole as role type and then in rolename refer your join.